# pdf regexp match on php

Tags: php, regex

regexp isnt one of my strong skills so need a bit of your help on this, have this regexp to get pdf url on a site source code

```
if (preg_match("/http\:\/\/.*?\.pdf/i", $source)) {
```

which work ok most of the times but of example when I get sites with link urls like

http://doc.pdfsomething.com/somemore/name.pdf

I am getting as match http://doc.pdf and not the complete pdf url.

Any regexp guru, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to match relative URLs as well, or will they always have 'http' at the start?

Comment: First I doubt that you really match a string like `...pdf` with a pattern looking for `...mp3`, then I doubt that if that was a "typo" you really get the outer part of the matched pattern, with the inner part magically snipped out and third that regex is invalid and you should have gotten an error. So please don't make things complicated, show your _real_ code and goal. No one here will sue you because you try to download music.

Comment: there is always an http at start

Comment: arkascha you are right, my bad with the typo, the site stripped some slashes from the regex but it normally work, just having problem on the explained scenario.

Comment: Please read my _full_ comment above (you may have to reload this page once). Think about it. _Then_ answer...

Comment: I have edited the question to pude the line as code, hope is make more sense now. thank you

Comment: Getting better with all the edits. Would have been much easier to post the original line of code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try matching on a word boundary

```
preg_match("/http:\/\/.*?\.pdf\b/i", $source)
```

Meaning that `.pdf` will only be matched if there is a non-word character after the `pdf` such as `"`, whitespace, etc..

Alternatively, if you know the URL is always going to be followed up with a specific character (double quotes `"` ?), then you could use

```
preg_match("/http:\/\/.*?\.pdf\"/i", $source)
```

Comment: Also an invalid regex... I would suggest something like `preg_match('/http:\/\/.*?\.pdf\b/i', $source);`...

Comment: You forgot to escape `//`.

Comment: The regex is at least valid now. But I don't see why this should answer the OPs question...

Comment: @arkascha why not? The way I see it, his non-greedy `*` operator is stopping prematurely at `http://doc.pdf`, and we need to get to the end of the full URL.

Comment: `http://doc.pdf` is not a URL. Something important is magically missing there according to the OPs description. _That_ is the question. And it is impossible with the given code.

Comment: The problem is that his regex is matching `http://doc.pdf` from `http://doc.pdfdocs.com/xyz` because of non-greedy `*`. My regex tries to address this to hit the end of the URL.

Comment: So you really believe the OP tries to match `http://doc.pdfsomething.com/somemore/name.pdf`? With all the edits of the "accidential typos" in there? OK...